# ggplot2, I get an error saying 'Each group consists of only one observation.'

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I see that there are other questions with the same problem but I do not understand the solutions listed for these questions.

My problem is that I grouped a data frame, using the `dplyr` package, by the `Year` column and then I used the `summarized` function of the `dplyr` package to sum two different columns. Now I am trying to use the `ggplot2` package to plot one of the summed columns against the year but I keep on getting the error

```
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. 
Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

My code for making the plot is

```
g <- ggplot(data, aes(Year, Fatalities)) + geom_line()
```

So what exactly am I doing wrong, I do not understand why the error shows `geom_path`, I do not even have that parameter in my code and when I do add `geom_path()` to my code, the same error pops up twice.

Edit: Here is how the top portion of the data frame looks like:

```
 Year     Fatalities    Injuries 
1 1950          70        659 
2 1951          34        524 
3 1952         230       1915 
4 1953         519       5131 
5 1954          36        715 
6 1955         129        926
```

Comment: I just added how the data looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function geom_line() you need to ad the parameter group inside of the function aes()

example

```
ggplot(df, aes(year, Observations))+geom_line(aes(colour=type, group=type))
```

this groups de data by the variable type, without this setting it sent me the same error as you, this changes the data so eachpoint isnt a diferent kind of observation and its impossible to relate them with a line.

if you dont need multiple lines try adding one more colum where all the observations have the same value (ex. "Set") and set the group parameter by that variable.

Comment: So your code worked when I added the changed

    `geom_line()`

to 

    `geom_line(group = 'character')`

but I am still wondering why did I have to do this, what do you mean that each point is a different kind of observation unless I add the `group` parameter to `geom_line()`?